# CodeSignal - 'Mutate Array'

Tags: python

The coding question asks:

> Given an integer n and an array a of length n, your task is to apply the following mutation to a:
>
> Array a mutates into a new array b of length n. For each i from 0 to n
> - 1, b[i] = a[i - 1] + a[i] + a[i + 1]. If some element in the sum a[i - 1] + a[i] + a[i
> + 1] does not exist, it should be set to 0. For example, b[0] should be equal to 0 + a[0] + a[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8Uvw.png).

My Code:

```
def solution(n, a):
    b = [None] * n
    for i in range(0, n-1):
        print('i = ', i)
        if i <= 0:
            b[i] = 0 + a[i] + a[i+1]
            print('IF 1')
        elif i >= n-1:
            b[i] = a[i-1] + a[i] + 0
            print('IF 2')
        else:
            b[i] = a[i-1] + a[i] + a[i+1]
            print('IF 3')
    return b
```

The issue is that the for loop does not seem to run a sufficient amount of times, and I cannot change the range according to the question. Any ideas? See results below.

[image]

Comment: *"and I cannot change the range according to the question"* - Really? That is odd. The range should be `range(0, n)` (or just `range(n)`, which is equivalent to that).

Comment: 0-n throws an error, it passes the first test case but fails one where the input is n=1 and a=[9]

Comment: Remember that Python `range()` is exclusive of the end value. So if you want `i` to iterate from `0` to `n-1`, you need to use `range(n)`. Where does the question say that you can't change the `range()` argument?

Comment: the question specifies range(0, n-1) 0-n o just n throws an index out of bounds error

Comment: Are you saying that the question requires you not to write `range(n)`, or just that you weren't able to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

The other solution failed for single element array. This should work fine.

```
def solution(a):
    b = []
    #print(b)
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if len(a) == 1:
            b.append(a[0])
        else:

            if i == 0:
                # b[i] = 0 + a[i] + a[i+1]
                b.append(0 + a[i] + a[i+1])
                print(b[i])
            elif i >= len(a) - 1:
                b.append(a[i - 1] + a[i] + 0)
            else:
                # b[i] =  a[i - 1] + a[i] + a[i + 1]
                b.append(a[i - 1] + a[i] + a[i + 1])
    return b
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote "For each i from 0 to n - 1, b[i] = ...".

Since we're probably going to use `range()`, let's start by examining how it works with a handful of experiments.

Experiment #1: This code ...

```
n = 5
for i in range(0, n-1):
    print(i)
```

... produces this output:

```
0
1
2
3
```

In other words, `range(0, n-1)` only produces the values `0` through `n-2`.

Experiment #2: This code ...

```
n = 5
for i in range(0, n):
    print(i)
```

... produces this output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

From this second experiment, we see that `range(0, n)` is the way to correctly produce the values `0` through `n-1`, which is the task specified in your question.

Let's do one final experiment.

Experiment #3: The following code ...

```
n = 5
for i in range(n):
    print(i)
```

... produces this output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

The output for `range(n)` is exactly the same as for `range(0, n)`. This experiment demonstrates that although `range(0, n)` matches the requirements of the task in your question, so does the slightly simpler expression `range(n)`.

Now that we have clarified how `range()` works, let's try the following slight modification of the code sample in your question:

```
def solution(n, a):
    b = [None] * n
    for i in range(n):
        print('i = ', i)
        if i <= 0:
            b[i] = 0 + a[i] + a[i+1]
            print('IF 1')
        elif i >= n-1:
            b[i] = a[i-1] + a[i] + 0
            print('IF 2')
        else:
            b[i] = a[i-1] + a[i] + a[i+1]
            print('IF 3')
    return b
a = [4, 0, 1, -2, 3]
b = solution(5, a)
print(b)
```

This code runs without any errors and its output is:

```
i =  0
IF 1
i =  1
IF 3
i =  2
IF 3
i =  3
IF 3
i =  4
IF 2
[4, 5, -1, 2, 1]
```

Problem solved!